# How to deploy a 3rd party set of libs to Nexus

Tags: maven, nexus, dcm4che, maven-deploy-plugin

I want to deploy a 3rd party set of libraries to nexus after building them from the source using maven.

I thought I'd be able to simply use `mvn deploy` but I get the following message:

```
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ dcm4che-parent ---
Uploading: scp://www.dcm4che.org:443/home/maven2/org/dcm4che/dcm4che-parent/3.3.7/dcm4che-parent-3.3.7.pom
The authenticity of host 'www.dcm4che.org' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 41:7f:10:be:8d:15:30:f1:91:59:95:c7:5d:63:f7:31.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting? (yes/no): yes
Password: :
```

This looks to me like it's trying to deploy to the www.dcm4che.org and not my nexus repo.

Can I not use `mvn deploy` in this way?

I can deploy my own libs to nexus this way without any problems.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

After following the advice in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37995279/820657) I executed the following command:

```
mvn deploy -DaltDeploymentRepository=nexus::default::http://192.168.50.200:8081/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty
```

and I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project dcm4che-parent: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact org.dcm4che:dcm4che-parent:pom:3.3.7 from/to nexus (http://192.168.50.200:8081/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty): Failed to transfer file: http://192.168.50.200:8081/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/org/dcm4che/dcm4che-parent/3.3.7/dcm4che-parent-3.3.7.pom. Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]
```

I have added an entry in my `settings.xml` as follows:

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>thirdparty</id>
        <username>deployment</username>
        <password>password</password>
        <configuration></configuration>
    </server>
</servers>
```

**2nd UPDATE**

I have tried the following command line variations but still can't get it to work. The maven documentation isn't any help.

```
mvn deploy -DaltDeploymentRepository=thirdparty::default::http://192.168.50.200:8081
```

produces the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project dcm4che-parent: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact org.dcm4che:dcm4che-parent:pom:3.3.7 in thirdparty (http://192.168.50.200:8081) -> [Help 1]
```

and

```
mvn deploy -DaltDeploymentRepository=thirdparty::default::http://192.168.50.200:8081/nexus/
```

produces the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project dcm4che-parent: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact org.dcm4che:dcm4che-parent:pom:3.3.7 from/to thirdparty (http://192.168.50.200:8081/nexus/): Failed to transfer file: http://192.168.50.200:8081/nexus/org/dcm4che/dcm4che-parent/3.3.7/dcm4che-parent-3.3.7.pom. Return code is: 405, ReasonPhrase: HTTP method PUT is not supported by this URL. -> [Help 1]
```

and

```
mvn deploy -DaltDeploymentRepository=nexus::default::http://192.168.50.200:8081/nexus/content/repositories/
```

produces the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project dcm4che-parent: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact org.dcm4che:dcm4che-parent:pom:3.3.7 in nexus (http://192.168.50.200:8081/nexus/content/repositories/) -> [Help 1]
```

**Final UPDATE**

For anyone else who might stumble across this, the following command worked. Thanks to A_Di-Matteo for his help.

```
mvn deploy -DaltDeploymentRepository=thirdparty::default::http://192.168.50.200:8081/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty
```

Comment: First i have doubts that using `scp` as protocol is a good idea nor usually used by Nexus. (http/https) is used. Furthermore you need to change the distributionManagement somewhere in pom.xml....

Comment: I don't know where or how `scp` comes into the deployment. It's nothing I have specified, knowingly.

Comment: @ksl the id in your settings snippet is `thirdparty` while from command line you passed `nexus`, that's a mismatch

Comment: @ksl from your second update, you are using the option correctly, but the url you are passing is not. You should pass a valid repository URL like `http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases` where `releases` is a configured repository on your Nexus. So it is not an issue with the `deploy` plugin in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably refering to the [`dcm4che-parent-3.3.7.pom`](http://www.dcm4che.org/maven2/org/dcm4che/dcm4che-parent/3.3.7/dcm4che-parent-3.3.7.pom) artifact, from which:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>www.dcm4che.org</id>
      <name>dcm4che Repository</name>
      <url>scp://www.dcm4che.org:443/home/maven2</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

As you can see, its `distributionManagement` is refering to the host mentioned in the build error, which is used as the default one.

If you want to deploy to your internal Nexus, you should then use the [`altDeploymentRepository`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html#altDeploymentRepository) option:

> Specifies an alternative repository to which the project artifacts should be deployed (other than those specified in `<distributionManagement>`). 
>   Format: `id::layout::url`.

Its user property is `altDeploymentRepository`.

Hence, you can invoke Maven as following:

```
mvn clean deploy -DaltDeploymentRepository=yourId::layout::URL
```

Which should match a repository specified in your Maven `settings.xml`.

---

As a general rule, you should not upload to Nexus public artifacts in this way: Nexus can retrieve them for you and be used as a further centralized cache/governance point for other remote repositories.

If you are changing public artifacts and then publishing them in your internal Nexus, then it is really adviced to change their [Maven coordinates](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates), at least adding a `classifier` specifying something related to your patch/company-name/useful-detail.

Comment: So I should just add the dcm4che repo to my nexus config then? And when I build my application which depends on dcm4che maven will pull in what it needs from it and build it then?

Comment: @ksl yes, that's the recommended approach, no need to upload each and every external dependency you need. Nexus will pull them for you and store in its cache.